# Allocate memory for struct array element (string)

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, struct

I am trying to read from keyboard and store the info in my struct book. The user is asked to enter the array size and I dynamically allocate the size to my book array. But when n > 1, the run time error is exc_bad_access. I don't know why it works when n = 1 and it doesn't work when n > 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book
{
    char *title;
    char *author;
    double price;
};

int main()
{
    int n, i = 0;
    printf("please enter the value for n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct book *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct book) * n);
    stack->author = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    stack->title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    //allocate memory for book and struct members
    while (i < n )
    {
        printf("Please enter the title\n");
        scanf("%s", stack[i].title);
        printf("Please enter the author\n");
        scanf("%s", stack[i].author);
        printf("Please enter the price\n");
        scanf("%lf", &stack[i].price);
        i ++;
    }
    free(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is redundant as it's `1` per definition.

Comment: My thought here is be able to set the upper limit for the input in terms of char number, so I think it is necessary to keep it in place right?

Comment: use a length specifier with `%s` to prevent buffer overflow. Also you may need to reconsider the choice of input method if there are any books with multiple words in their title or author name!

Comment: `sizeof (char) * 100` equals `1 * 100` equals `100`. So what is the need for using `sizeof (char)`? Coding `100` would do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating enough structures for any size of elements you input, but **not the space for the buffers**:

```
struct book *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct book) * n);
stack->author = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
stack->title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
// what about stack[1].author, stack[2].author and the rest??
```

This will work instead:

```
struct book *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct book) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    stack[i].author = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    stack[i].title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
}
```

And remember to free your memory as well.

Comment: In C casting the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc` isn't necessary nor is it recommended. Just do not do this.

Answer (score 2):

For each book in the stack, you have to allocate memory for the author and the title.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    stack[i].author = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    stack[i].title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
}
```

You are only allocating memory for the first element.

Comment: stack->author = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
stack->title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for

```
char *title;
char *author;
```

When you do `struct book *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct book) * n);` memory is allocated for `char*` pointers (4 or 8 bytes depending on platform you're building).

So you need to allocate some memory for inside values

```
while (i < n )
{
    char *title = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Please enter the title\n");
    scanf("%s", title);
    stack[i].title = title;
    .....
    i ++;
}
```

Comment: Why the intermediate `title`? Why not allocated to and read into the struct's member directly?